# Variable issues in php class

Tags: php, class

I have an issue calling a simple variable into another variable in php class:

When i write it, page just doesent load.

any idea why?

Iv tried to remove public attribute

```
class KAKAI {


public $g = 'kkk';
public $p = $g;

}
```

Just trying to understand my mistake

Comment: First, object properties are accessed using `$this->propertyNameHere`, second `public $p = $g;` just doesn't make sense. You can only assign things that evaluate to a constant in a property declaration. Assuming $g is intended as the property above, you'd set it in the constructor with e.g. `public function __construct() { $this->p = $this->g; }`.

Comment: Thank you brah, i just reviewed the class logic and got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$g` doesn't exist until run-time and it is an object variable, so assign it in the constructor:

```
class KAKAI {

    public $g = 'kkk';
    public $p = '';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->p = $this->g;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Please mark as accepted if it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you call a class variable outside the class.

```
<?php
class KAKAI {
    public $g = 'kkk';
    public $p = 'ppp';
}

$class = new KAKAI();
echo $class->g;
?>
```

Also, this line is not valid

```
public $p = $g;
```